# JAVA GUI Progress information - how to ensure it is updated

Tags: java, awt

I have an application that when the GUI GO button is clicked it does hundreds of file copies and I want to update a text box on the GUI to show progress, but the GUI remains frozen with the GO button clicked in until it finishes.

I created a similar GUI that just counts in order to test updating a text box to get progress information. In order to get that working I needed to push the counting process into a thread - presumably this then releases the event handler for the GO button. Everything worked fine then.

So, I followed the same strategy for the file copying program but it didn't work there - the GUI still remains frozen until the end.

How can I get these text fields to update.

I tried getting the process thread to Yield, and then to Yield and Sleep. I tried using panel.invalidate() and panel.repaint(). But none of these things work.

Comment: Oracle has a rad tutorial, [Creating a GUI With Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/index.html).  Skip the Netbeans section.  You use a Swing Timer to do background processes in your GUI.  The [Concurrency in Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html) section discusses how to do this.

Comment: Thanks for the link. Reading through it I found SwingWorker - that solved the problem.